# Custom STL Containers

Tags: stl, containers

I have written code that allows one to traverse mapped data in the order it was entered.

The solution I coded a couple of times was:

Given a keytype, K, and and data type, D,
     std::map
     std::vector

When one wanted to randomly find a data entry, use `map.find(K)`.  When one wanted to traverse the map in entry order, use `std::vector::iterator (begin(), end()]`.

This was fine, but as an exercise, I wanted to write this `'OrderedMap'` as an STL compliant container.  I also have (stripped down to this discussion):

```
template <typename K, typename D>
class OrderedMapValue
{
private:
    K first_ref;
    std::map<K,size_t>& m;
    std::vector<D>& v;
public:
    const K& first
    D& second
    assignment operator=(const D& data) 
    {
        std::map<K,size_t>::const_iterator iter = m.find(first_ref);
        v[iter.second] = data;  // error checking of iter stripped
    }
};
```

Further assuming

```
template <typename K, typename D>
class OrderedMap
{
public:
     typename OrderedMapValue<K,D>& OrderedMap<K,D>::operator[](const K&);
     // snip...
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(std::string s) : _my_data(s) {}
private:
    std::string _my_data;
};
```

The following code works:

```
OrderedMap<std::string,MyClass*> omap;
omap["MyKey"] = new MyClass("dummy");
```

However, this code does not:

```
OrderedMap::iterator iter = omap.find("MyKey");
MyClass * obj = iter->second;
delete obj;
iter->second = new MyClass("dummy");
```

Assuming I have done something 
  a) Structurally silly or
  b) Unnecessarily complex, how should this be done?

I realize that I'm likely reinventing the wheel here, but again, this effort is mainly to increase my knowledge of STL containers, their design patterns and proper use.

Thanks in advance for any insights,

Comment: Shouldn't the usage of the iterator be `iter->second`?  Where `iter` is an `OrderedMap::iterator` and `*iter` is an `OrderedMapValue`?

Comment: That's right -- put in an answer.

Comment: You are correct, I had accepted your answer.  Conceptually, you really nailed the essence of what was needed.

When I took a closer look at the TYPE& operator[] methods, I realized that there were some issues that needed to be ironed out so that code marked as an accepted solution would not mislead folks.
My (good) intention was to provide a proven solution, but I'm now just getting back to this.

Comment: When you say "this code does not [work]", what does mean? Wont compile? Wont link? Throws an exception? Crashes? Computer catches fire?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a compiler right now to test this, so there could be errors, but I think you want it more like:

```
template <typename K, typename D>
class OrderedMap
{
private:
        std::map<K,size_t> &m;
        std::vector<D> &v;
public:
    typename pair<K,D> TYPE;

        TYPE& operator[](const K &k)
    {
        return v[ m[ k ]];
    }

    TYPE& operator[](size_t idx)
    {
        return v[ idx ];
    }

    pair<iterator,bool> insert( const TYPE& pair )
    {
        map<K, size_t>::const_iterator iter;
        iter = m.find( pair.first );

        if( iter != m.end() )
            return make_pair( v[ iter.second], false );

        m.insert( make_pair( pair->first, v.size() ));
        v.push_back( pair->second );

        return make_pair(  v.last() , inserted );
    }

    iterator &begin()
    {
        return v.begin();
    }
    // etc
};
```

Comment: Yes - that is exactly what I was looking for.  I appreciate the time you took to provide the sample.

Comment: The `OrderedMap` should hold the map and vector by value, not reference. `TYPE` should probably be `pair<const K,D>`, to match how map works.  Also, he probably wants `operator[](const K&) to return a `D&`.

Answer (score 0):

In `OrderedMapValue::operator=`, you have:

```
    std::map<K,size_t>::const_iterator iter = m.find(first_ref);
```

What is `first_ref`? The code doesn't reference it (no pun intended) elsewhere.  It looks to me like it might be a vestige from an older implementation, replaced elsewhere by the public member

`const K& first`.

Could this be the problem?

**EDIT** from the comments:  The code doesn't show that first_ref is initialized anywhere; so for all I can tell, the call to `m.find(first_ref)` is searching for an empty string, rather than the key for the OrderedMapValue.

Comment: first_ref is the non-const private member of OrderedMapValue.  I was trying to keep first const, but still give myself a means to set the key member.

Comment: But where is first_ref initialized?  For all I can tell,
m.find(first_ref) is searching for an empty string, rather than the string that you're overwriting.

Comment: Dan,

In my effort to keep the code brief, I edited the code you needed to see.  In hindsight, I probably should have left that detail off since it was not needed for this discussion...